# Using XAML ItemTemplates with Metro UI

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro

The default "split view" template for a Metro application written in C# makes use of an `ItemTemplate` attribute in the `ListView` tag. I'm just getting started with XAML and C#, so it's all still a bit overwhelming.

I understand that the `ItemsSource` is used to provide the *data collection* to the view, but I'm a bit confused as to how the `ListView` knows what to display from those model classes. Is this defined by the `ItemTemlate`? There's a snippet of code:

```
...ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SnapListItemTemplate}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource SnapListTileStyle}" ItemsPanel="{StaticResource SnapListItemsPanelTemplate}"...
```

I don't really understand *most* of that line. Where are these `SnapList*` options defined? Is there a provided list of available templates, or are these all defined my project somewhere? Does the `SnapListItemTemplate` look for a specific set of ivars to display? Can this template be altered or "subclassed"?

For example, there are a number of properties on the model classes like `title`, `subtitle`, etc. And I'm curious as to how the `ListView` knows to pull out those specific values, and also how it knows to lay them out. What if I want to change the name of the `subtitle` ivar to `subtext`? How is the item template updated?

Comment: How did you create your project?  Are you using one of the standard project templates?

Comment: Yea, I'm using the Visual C#, Windows Metro Style, Split Application. (Or the Grid Application, they're both very similar and the question applies equally to both.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SnapList*` templates should be defined in your project somewhere.

The binding is `{StaticResource ...}` which means that the template/style or whatever is usually defined in some XAML file.

If you search the project (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) for the names they should turn up, probably in a file called `Styles.xaml`.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I missed that. They were all defined in one of my root XAML files. (App.xaml, for those using the template projects.) Things are starting to make much more sense now. Thanks! (I can award the bounty in 20 hours, so you'll have to sit tight.) In the meantime, does StaticResource have to be defined (i.e. does it explicitly mean App.xaml), or does it just mean "in one of the XAML files in my project"?

Comment: @craig - It's doesn't have to be `App.xaml` but you need to make sure the resource dictionary it's in can be seen by the code where you are using it.

Comment: @Craig The static resource walks the element tree looking for a match for the key value.  In your case the framework looks first for SnapListItemTemplate key in your ListView, then it's parent and so on until it gets to the root element.Then it looks in App.xaml.  The first match that is finds is the resource that is used.  In your case the match was in app.xaml

Comment: @WaltRitscher Perfect, that makes sense. Thank you very much for the clarification. I noticed the `x:Key` in some of the XAML files, that would explain its purpose.

Comment: Resharper 7 Beta now also supports going to the definition of static resources, along with a ton of other goodies in the XAML views.